# node.js api gateway implementation and passport authentication

Tags: node.js, passport.js, microservices

I am working on implementing a microservices-based application using node.js.  While searching for examples on how to implement the api gateway, I came across the following article that seems to provide an example on implementing the api gateway: https://memz.co/api-gateway-microservices-docker-node-js/.  Though, finding example for implementing the api gateway pattern in node.js seems to be a little hard to come by so far, this article seemed to be a really good example.

There are a few items that are still unclear and I am still have issues finding doc. on.

1) Security is a major item for the app. I am developing, I am having trouble seeing where the authentication should take place (i.e. using passport, should I add the authentication items in the api gateway and pass the jwt token along with the request to the corresponding microservice as the user's logged in information is needed for certain activities?  The only issue here seems to be that all of the microservices would need passport in order to decrypt the jwt token to get the user's profile information.  Would the microservice be technically, inaccessible to the outside world except through the api gateway as this seems to be the aim?

2) How does this scenario change if I need to scale to multiple servers with docker images on each one?  How would this affect load balancing, as it seems like something would have to sit at a higher level to deal with load balancing?

Comment: Possibly [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com) is a better place to ask.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I can tell that much depends on your application requirements. Really.
I'm now past the 5 years of experience in production microservices using several languages going from medium to very large scale system.

None of them shared the same requirements, and without having a deep understanding of what you need and what are your business (product) requirements it would be hard to know what's the right answer, by the way I'll try to share some experience to help you get it right.

Ideally you want the security to be encapsulated in an external service, so that you can update and apply new policies faster. Also you'll be able to deprecate all existing tokens should you find a breach in your system or if someone in your team inadvertedly pushes some secret key (or cert) to an external service.

You could handle authentication on each single service or using an edge newtwork tool (such as the API Gateway). Becareful choosing how to handle it because each one has it's own privileges:

1. Choosing the API Gateway your services will remain lighter and do not need to know anything about the authentication steps, but surely at some point you'll need to know who the authenticated user is and you need some plain reference to it (a JSON record, a link or ID to a "user profile" service). How you do it it's up to your requirements and we can even go deeper talking about different pros and cons about each possible choice applicable for your case.
2. Choosing to handle it at the service level requires you (and your teams) to understand better about the security process taking place (you can hide it with a good library) and you'll need to give them support from your security team (it's may also be yourself btw you know the more service implementing security, the more things you'll have to think about to avoid adding unnecessary features). The big problem here is that you'll often end up stopping your tasks to think about what would help you out on this particular service and you'll be tempted to extend your authentication service (and God, unless you really know what you're doing, don't add a single call not needed for authentication purposes).

One thing is easy to be determined: you surely need to think about tokens (jwt, jwe or, again, whatever your requirements impose).

JWT has good benefits, but data is exposed to spoofing, so never put in there sensitive data or things you wouldn't publicly share about your user (e.g. an ID is probably fine, while security questions or resolution to 2FA would not). JWE is an encrypted form of the spec. A common token (with no meaning) would require a backend to get the data, but it works much like cookie-sessions and data is not leaving your servers.

You need to define yourself the boundaries of your services and do yourself a favor: make each service boundaries clean, defined and standard.

Try to define common policies and standardize interactions, I know it may be easier to add a queue here, a REST endpoint there, a RPC there, but you'll soon end up with a bunch of IPC you will not be able to handle anymore and it will soon catch your attention.

Also if your business solution is pretty heavy to do I don't think it's a good idea to do yourself the API Gateway, Security and so on. I'd go with open source, community supported (or even company-backed if you have some budget) and production-tested solutions.

By definition microservice architectures are very dynamic, you'll fight to keep it immutable between each deployment version, but unless you're a big firm you cannot effort keeping live thousands of servers. This means you'll discover bugs that only presents under certain circumstances you cannot spot in other environments (it happens often to not be able to reproduce them).

By choosing to develop the whole stack yourself you agree with having to deal with maintenance and bug-discovery in your whole stack. So when you try to load a page that has 25 services interacting you know it may be failing because of a bug in: your API Gateway, your Security implementation, your token parser, your user account service, your business service A to N, your database service (if any), your database load balance (if any), your database instance.

I know it's tempting to do everything, but try to keep it flat and do what you need to do. By following this path you'll think about your product, which I think is what's the most important think to do now.

To complete my answer, about the scaling issues:
it doesn't matter. Whatever choice you pick it will scale seamlessly:

1. API Gateway should be able to work on a pool of backends (so from that server you should be able to redirect to N backend machines you can put live when you need to, you can even have some API to support automatic registration of new instances, or even simples put the IP of an Elastic Load Balancer or HAproxy or equivalents, and as you add backends to them it will just work -you have moved the multiple IPs issue from the API Gateway to one layer down).
2. If you handle authentication at services level (and you have an API Gateway) see #1
3. If you handle authentication at services level (without an API Gateway) then you need to look at some other level in your stack: load balancing (layer 3 or layer 7), or the DNS level, you can use several features of DNS to put different IPs to answer from, using even advanced features like Anycast if you need latency distribution.

I know this answer introduced a lot of other questions, but I really tried to answer your question. The fact is that you need to understand and evaluate a lot of things when planning a microservice architecture and I'd not write a SLOC without a very-written-plan printed on every wall of my office.

You'll often need to go mental focus and exit from a single service to review the global vision and check everything is going fine.

I don't want to scare you, I'm rather trying to make you think to succeed.
I just want you to make sure you correctly evaluated all of the possibilities before to decide to do everything from scratch.

P.S. Should you choose to act using an API gateway be sure to limit services to only accept requests through it. On the same machine just start listening on localhost, on multiple machines you'll need some advanced networking rule depending on your operating system.

Good Luck!

Comment: This comment not only gives a good overview of the decision making of where to place your security, it also gives a nice solid opinion regarding micro service architecture. I definitely enjoyed it, /clap